# Сбились комментарии в VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

В последнее время при установке комментария VSC обворачивает блок в {# мой код #}. Причем совершенно не волнует css, html или php. Подскажите куда копать? в каком фале можно поменять настройки. Спасибо

Comment: А что такое - _установка комментария_, куда или где вы его устанавливаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположу проблему. Либо у вас не верный `Language Mode`, либо было установлено расширение, которое переопределяет знаки комментариев. Про второй случай не могу сказать, а вот про первый приведу пример на `html`, как увидеть и поменять.

Чтобы увидеть все доступные языки для `Language Mode`, можно воспользовать сочетанием клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (windows OS)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случае для файлов с расширением `.html` поддерживаются два `Language Mode`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в завимости от того, какой я использую у меня по разному используется комментирование блока кода

Для `Django HTML`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `HTML`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы увидеть, какой режим языка включен в данный момент, то необходимо посмотреть в правый нижний угол окна `VScode`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию здесь же, его можно изменить

Документация по описаному лежит [здесь](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview)